# Swift: Why my label doesn't update even I employ a timer to change its text attribute?

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to implement a simple clock, and here is my storyboard:

[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        _ = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateClock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateClock() {
        self.timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The label just keeps displaying `00:00:00`. Could anyone please give me some suggestion about that?

Comment: BTW, please don't do `Foo.init(...)`. This is totally unnecessary; the Swiftier way is to just write `Foo(...)`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `Timer` (which you have done) and **schedule** it. That adds it to the run loop so it will actually fire.

The easiest way to do it is to use `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`, which both creates and schedules the `Timer`:

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateClock),
    userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Note that you should probably also store a weak reference to the `Timer`, so you can invalidate it when you want it to stop firing.